# node.js "TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth_token' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, jwt

Hello when I try and redirect to my welcome page I get this type error. The TypeError is being called on my verifyToken.js file when trying to find the value of the req.cookies.auth_token

Also note that the index.js file has a lot of code that probably isn't relevant to this question but I added it to this question just to be safe and make sure I'm not missing anything obvious.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth_token' of undefined
at module.exports (C:\Users\Likel\Documents\GitHub\Node.js_Authenticator\routes\verifyToken.js:10:39)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Likel\Documents\GitHub\Node.js_Authenticator\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\Likel\Documents\GitHub\Node.js_Authenticator\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Likel\Documents\GitHub\Node.js_Authenticator\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Likel\Documents\GitHub\Node.js_Authenticator\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\Likel\Documents\GitHub\Node.js_Authenticator\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Likel\Documents\GitHub\Node.js_Authenticator\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\Likel\Documents\GitHub\Node.js_Authenticator\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at urlencodedParser (C:\Users\Likel\Documents\GitHub\Node.js_Authenticator\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:91:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Likel\Documents\GitHub\Node.js_Authenticator\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

Here is my code

**verifyToken.js**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const express = require("express");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());

module.exports = function (req,res,next){
            const token = req.cookies.auth_token;
            if (!token) {
              return res.status(403).send('Access Denied');
            }
            try {
              const data = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
              req.userId = data.id;
              next();
            } catch(err) {
              return res.sendStatus(400).send('Invalid Token');
            }
    };
```

**auth.js**

```
//Login
router.post('/login', async (req,res) => {
    const {error} = loginValidation(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    //Checking if eamil exist in database
    const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
    if(!user) return res.status(400).send('Invalid Email');

    //Check if password is correct
    const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if(!validPass) return res.status(400).send('Invalid password')
   
    //Creat and assign json web token
    const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
    return res
    .cookie("auth_token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.TOKEN_SECRET === "production",
    })
    .status(200),
    res.redirect('/welcome');
    
});


module.exports = router;
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
//Import Routes
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth');
const postRoute = require('./routes/posts');
const res = require('express/lib/response');
const { verify } = require('jsonwebtoken');
const verifyJsonWebToken = require('./routes/verifyToken');
const { cookie } = require('express/lib/response');

dotenv.config();


//Set views
app.set('view-engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false }))


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.ejs')
});

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login.ejs')
});

app.get('/register', (req, res) => {
    res.render('register.ejs')
});

app.get('/welcome', verifyJsonWebToken, (req, res) => {
    res.render('welcome.ejs', { username: 'username'})
});

//Sends From Info to database
app.post('/register', authRoute);
app.post('/login', authRoute);


//Adds css to pages
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + 'public/css'))

//Connect to DB
mongoose.connect(
    process.env.DB_CONNECT,
() => console.log('connected to db!')
);



//Middleware
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
//Route Middlewares
app.use('/api/user', authRoute);
app.use('/api/posts', postRoute);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server Up and Running'));
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: which means `req.cookies` are `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using `app.use(cookieParser());` at beginning before using express routes.

Comment: I've tried that it didn't fix the problem.